# How do I access a Google Chart object after instantiation?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'd like to change properties of my chart after its initial draw (e.g. change the range of a ChartRangeFilter using an HTML button). I'm having a hard time finding how to access the chart object on the page, but I'm sure it's available somewhere in the `window` namespace.

Comment: Isn't the chart object assigned to a variable? For example `var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(...)`.

Comment: It is, but it's being called within a function (drawChart [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start)), so it's destroyed when it goes out of scope (i.e. once the chart is instantiated).

Comment: One solution would be to take the `chart` variable out of the scope of that function so you can reference it elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is I have lots of objects, so making them all global would be messy, and I'd have to rename them all separately. I imagine there's a better way. With CKEditor, you always have access to instances using `var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.article_name`, since CKEDITOR is a global object. This is kind of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this now. Bind the chart to a local variable, and attach handlers within scope:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(...);

$('body').on('click', 'button.update', function() {
    chart.draw(...);
}
```